# SIM800c - Disable "OVER-VOLTAGE WARNNING" unsolicited messages

Tags: arduino, serial-port, at-command, sim800, arduino-esp32

How to disable "OVER-VOLTAGE WARNNING" URC on sim800c?
Im using SIM800C with esp32, is there any at commands to disable these warnings?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, and nothing to do with Arduino or even ESP32.

Comment: @hcheung questions about AT commands are actually considered [on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403258/11336762) by the community.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the warnings in the [SIM800C datasheet](https://www.elecrow.com/download/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.02.pdf):

> If the voltage ≥ 4.3V, the following URC will be reported
> **`OVER-VOLTAGE WARNING`**

Furthermore, the datasheet states that the module will automatically shut down due to overvoltage if supply voltage exceeds 4.4V (**`OVER-VOLTAGE POWER OFF`** URC). This behavior indicates that the module will automatically shut itself down due to negative factors. *There is no software interference with this behavior*.

Comment: I'm aware that edits should not intervene on the contents of an answer, but in this case it was a typo that actually invalidatedit (the description  you quoted was the one referring to another URC, an undervoltage one). Instead of writing my CC answer or relying in comments, I preferred to shorten time by editing myself the correction. Feel free to revert if you felt "violated".